# To run LED in series directly to power supply or not to?

Tags: led

O.k in need of experts. I have an LED project I'm working on. 175: 1w led beads all with the same specs which are; 3.2-3.4V & 350mA each. I wanted to know if i could run them in series to a power supply directly since my calculations of both leds & power supply currents seem to be within range. The power supply specs are: outputting 5V & 70A. When i multiplied 175(leds) x .35 i got 61.25. Which would be 61.25A. So since the current of the leds doesn't exceed the power supply current. Can i go for this set up or should i add more leds to the series to get the mA amount from the leds closer to the power supply current amount

Comment: I think you mean run the LEDs in parallel. And this would require inclusion of a series resistor (about 5 Ohms) for each LED (or at least for each group of LEDs if you are willing to match the group members).

Comment: Well I'm willing. Though I was trying to defeat the use of resistors... I guess that's the beauty of projects. "LEARNING" before going through trial & error. So if I take on the series set up connecting resistors. Wouldn't I lose power somewhere within the leds? & I kind of thought leds only take what they want from a power supply.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to operate the LEDs in a few series chains? Say groups of three of them in series from a 12 V supply? Or groups of six from a 24 V supply? Etc?

Comment: Because I want the leds to run at full potential while saving money but since you implied "groups of 3" I think that's not such a bad idea. Though I still want full potential from the series set up. Oh & to avoid super high temps.

Comment: LEDs consume current based on the voltage across them, they do NOT 'control their current and take just what they need'. Read up on LED characteristics. @Jonks suggestion makes sense too ...but I'd suggest you should go for a 36 V power supply with 10 LEDs in series and 18 chains, there are plenty of power supplies in the 200-350 W range available cheaply.

Comment: #Jack Creasey, that's exactly the info I needed in explanation with the graph that was provided. I'm definitely going to go with #Jonks advice because in my opinion it seems more conservative in many ways. Plus, you just confirmed my thoughts in which route to take. So I greatly appreciate the help from u guys... So should I get a 350w 36v at what Amps for the resistors?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with LEDs is that the current varies disproportionately with small changes in voltage.

[image]

*Figure 1. Typical LED current vs voltage curves. These curves are for 30 mA typical LEDs. Yours have a much higher current rating.*

If you follow the line for the white LED (W) you will see that if we increase the voltage from 3 to 3.5 V that the current doubles from 20 to 40 mA. In your case, with the higher powered LEDs, you would see an increase from 350 mA to, perhaps, 700 mA.

For this reason we control current typically by adding a resistor in series. As you point out, this is wasteful of energy and in a high-powered lighting plan as yours this becomes a significant problem.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZbTPx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Parallel and series connected LEDs.*

A better arrangement is to arrange the LEDs in series and power them from a constant current power supply of adequate voltage. In your case you might decide to limit the voltage to, say, 48 V on any string so you could drive 48/3.5 = 13 LEDs per string and feed these from one constant current driver. This is avoids all the parallel resistors and the associated power loss. The constant current source is set for 350 mA and the same current runs through all the LEDs in that string.

There are many options available to you. Hopefully this information will be enough to get you started.

Comment: Yoooooooo. O.k perfect. I understand now & even more of what the other guys were mentioning. #Transistor good stuff bro. Now I'm going to start a 2nd project... don't bug out if I ask any more future reference questions(which I will). Live to learn is the motto. Thanks #JackCreasley #jonk & #Transistor

Comment: @keLECTRIFY (Use the @, not the #, or else this site doesn't know how to let us know you said something.) Glad to hear things helped. If you put LEDs in series they will all have the same current in them (which is good.) It uses fewer resistors or else current control circuits this way, as well. The wasted power will very well be less, as well.

Comment: @Jonk clearly understood. I'm literally reading ALLLLLLLL of your posts. So my apologies for responding late but your profile is smashing with info. It's like a river of knowledge meets a waterfall of explanation. I think I'm beyond good on collecting info for now. Thanks to all who helped me... oh & last question for now; does resistor color coding matter or are all 4.7 ohm 1w resistors the same?

Comment: @keLECTRIFY: You can find some other articles written by me on my [LED website](http://lednique.com/parallel-leds/). They should be relevant and may even help!

Comment: @Transistor trust me bro I'm way ahead of you. Already been reading your write-ups. Using at least 3 to 4 Windows so I don't have to constantly click back & back & back & forward through the profiles. I kind of got glued to your profile forgetting about my whole led project because I realized you're an audio & electric engineer. I freaking love this website. I get to learn the best of both worlds.